# Using TestServer for error scenarios

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing

I am trying to use `TestServer` to verify how my application would behave if an exception. For example, in this sample I have a controller will call to a database but in my test I am deliberately setting up the `repository` to throw an exception.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository _repo;

    public ValuesController(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        this._repo.Execute();
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

I am expecting an internal server error to be returned. Although this works if were to F5 and run the application I was hoping to do this via `TestServer`.

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        using (var client = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<TestStartup>())
            .CreateClient())
        {
            var result = client.GetAsync("api/values").Result;
            Assert.Equal(result.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }

    public class TestStartup : Startup
    {
        protected override void ConfigureDependencies(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IRepository, FailingRepo>();
        }
    }
}

public class FailingRepo : IRepository
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Instead what I get is the test failing for:

> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (The method
>   or operation is not implemented.)

I can get this to work if I was to plug in some custom middleware at the start of the pipeline, something similar to this:

```
public class ErrorMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate next;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public ErrorMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger logger)
    {
        this.next = next;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await this.next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
    }
}
```

I remember being able to do this via Owin Test Server available in the full .NET framework. Any ideas how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

```
public class BasicTests 
    : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup> _factory;

    public BasicTests(WebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }
```

and instead of the  generic type `RazorPagesProject.Startup` use your own project to test. The factory will provide you the option to access to the routes you want and test they if they are perfoming as you want:

```
// Arrange
var client = _factory.CreateClient();
// Act
var response = await client.GetAsync("api/Values");
//
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
```

Comment: Just tried this and I get the error System.InvalidOperationException : No method 'public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)' found on 'AutoGeneratedProgram'. Alternatively, WebApplicationFactory1 can be extended and 'protected virtual IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()' can be overridden to provide your own IWebHostBuilder instance. Any ideas?

Comment: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modern-web-apps-azure-architecture/test-asp-net-core-mvc-apps